# rpmbuild isn't using the current working directory, instead using users home?

Tags: rpmbuild

When I use `rpmbuild` I get, *No such file or directory*.

```
# rpmbuild -ba ./SPECS/myFoo.spec
error: File /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/myFoo.tar.gz: No such file or directory
```

It seems to be reading from my home directory despite running the `rpmbuild` command from an entirely different user's home directory. However that doesn't change if I use `--root` (which is documented as *"Use the file system tree rooted at `DIRECTORY` for all operations."*)

```
# rpmbuild -ba ./SPECS/myFoo.spec --root /home/centos/myFoo/
error: File /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/myFoo.tar.gz: No such file or directory
```

What' the solution to getting this to look in the right place.

Comment: Why are you running `rpmbuild` as root?

Comment: I get `No such file or directory` when I run it as non-root too. `error: File /home/centos/rpmbuild/SOURCES/myFOO_rc1.tar.gz: No such file or directory`

Comment: I’m not asking if it works any better when running as a user; I’m asking why you’re running `rpmbuild` as root.

Comment: (I’m being curious, really; trying to understand what suggests that running `rpmbuild` is either needed or a potentially good idea.)

Comment: Because we develop as root. And because it didn't work as a regular user. But I don't see how that's relevant here, but feel free to ask more questions so long as they're related to this problem.

Comment: I'm just trying to build an rpm from a spec file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method to do this, is

```
rpmbuild --define "_topdir `pwd`" -ba ./SPECS/myFoo.spec
```

No idea if that's the right method.

Answer (score 4):

`rpmbuild` doesn’t particularly care about the current directory, except to find the files given to it as arguments. Everything else is based on the value of the `_topdir` macro. `rpmbuild` also really expects you to do all your building with a single directory structure.

You can define the root of `rpmbuild`’s directory structure permanently for any particular user by storing the appropriate value in `~/.rpmmacros`:

```
%_topdir /path/to/your/data
```

Or, as you determined, override `_topdir` every time you run `rpmbuild` with the `-D` option.

Comment: Let's say I have foo/SPECS/foo.spec, bar/SPECS/bar.spec, baz/SPECS/baz.spec. Is it possible to set %_topdir properly for foo/bar/baz? Or should I continue with my solution? Or am I doing something majorly wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, and I have used the follow solution.

Open the file `~/.rpmmacros`

and change the line:

`%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild`

for:

`%_topdir %(pwd)`

Now:

`rpmbuild -ba ./SPECS/myFoo.spec`

will work as excepted.